# Ruby: Continue a loop after catching an exception

Tags: ruby, exception, loops

Basically, I want to do something like this (in Python, or similar imperative languages):

```
for i in xrange(1, 5):
    try:
        do_something_that_might_raise_exceptions(i)
    except:
        continue    # continue the loop at i = i + 1
```

How do I do this in Ruby? I know there are the `redo` and `retry` keywords, but they seem to re-execute the "try" block, instead of continuing the loop:

```
for i in 1..5
    begin
        do_something_that_might_raise_exceptions(i)
    rescue
        retry    # do_something_* again, with same i
    end
end
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

In Ruby, `continue` is spelt `next`.

Comment: @Thayne [British spelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spelt#Etymology_1) isn't misspelling! The world does not revolve around the US. :-) (Don't feel bad. I revert Americanisation edits all the time.)

Comment: I appologize, I didn't reallize spelt was a valid spelling in british english.

Answer (score 65):

```
for i in 1..5
    begin
        do_something_that_might_raise_exceptions(i)
    rescue
        next    # do_something_* again, with the next i
    end
end
```

Comment: could you also suggest a way to output the exception that took place.

Comment: rescue => e
  e contains exception object, you could e.message, e.backtrace

Comment: You're in a loop, after the rescue, it will continue with the loop, whether there is a `next` or not in `rescue`.

Answer (score 9):

to print the exception:

```
rescue
        puts $!, $@
        next    # do_something_* again, with the next i
end
```